# freeRTOS Process switching

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, scheduling, freertos

I tried to do a task which was to create 2 tasks. 1 task is to run cyclically every 95 ms and take 30 ms of processor time, and the second task is to run cyclically up to 33 ms and takes 15 ms of processor time. I have a problem to adjust a function so that it takes the right time given as a function parameter. Should a software timer be used or is there a function timing tool in eclipse?

main.c :

```
xTaskHandle task1, task2;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
//  SystemClock_Config();
HAL_Init();
MX_GPIO_Init();

xTaskCreate(zadanie1, "Zadanie1", 128, "to jest nazwa zadania ", 1, & task1);
xTaskCreate(zadanie2, "Zadanie2", 256, "to jest nazwa zadania ", 1, & task2);

vTaskStartScheduler();

return 0;
}
```

lab1.c :

```
int iCPU_work(int czas_obliczen_ms) {
int a, b, wynik = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < czas_obliczen_ms; i++) {
  a++;
   b++;
wynik = a + b;
}
return wynik;
}

void zadanie1(void * parametry) {
char nazwa_zadania[16];

portTickType OstatnieWywolanie = 0;

strncpy(nazwa_zadania, (char * ) parametry, 15);

for (;;) {
  iCPU_work(30);
  LED1_TOGGLE();
  vTaskDelayUntil( & OstatnieWywolanie, 95);
  printf(nazwa_zadania);
 }
 vTaskDelete(NULL); // usuwa zadanie
 }

 void zadanie2(void * parametry) {
 portTickType OstatnieWywolanie = 0;
 char nazwa_zadania[16];

 strncpy(nazwa_zadania, (char * ) parametry, 15);
 for (;;) {
  iCPU_work(15);
  LED2_TOGGLE();
  vTaskDelayUntil( & OstatnieWywolanie, 33);
  printf(nazwa_zadania);
  }
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
  }

  void vApplicationIdleHook(void) {
  LED3_TOGGLE();
  }

  void vApplicationTickHook(void) {
  LED4_TOGGLE();
  }
```

Comment: Depending on the tick frequency you're using, you might be able to just busy-loop using [xTaskGetTickCount](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#xTaskGetTickCount) to measure elapsed time.

Comment: Couple of file-scope vars, to store the time when the tasks were last run, and a couple semaphores?  When each task starts, store the time.  When each task finishes, refer to the time the other task last ran, calculate how long a delay to the next other task run, sleep for that time, signal the semaphore for the other task and wait on the sema for the task just run. No need for busy-waiting.

Comment: @unwind It is not so easy to simulate CPU load using `xTaskGetTickCount` if `configUSE_TIME_SLICING == 1`. In that case all tasks with equal priority switched every tick in the round-robin manner and given task will use proportionally less CPU time

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, you are right -- except for the case the labwork is about CPU load simulation using busy loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that according to RMA/RMS, you are above the schedulability limit. Your CPU utilization is 30/95 + 15/33 == 0.77 which is more than ln(2). Your tasks are not harmonic, so you probably have a set of tasks that are "unschedulable". (Please google for RMA/RMS, or "schedulability limit").

Comment: Well, since the OP does not specify any performance constraints, or any hardware details, I assume that either occasional 'clashes' are acceptable,or that multiple cores are available to run both tasks simultaneously.